# How to get role names from member in discord

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to write user info command and want to show there user's roles but when I try to get their roles, I'm receiving their ids. How I can get only name of them?

```
# User info
@commands.command(aliases = ['usinfo'])
async def userinfo(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
    emb = discord.Embed(description = "**{}'s info**".format(member.mention), colour = member.color)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    channel = ctx.channel.id
    emb.set_author(name = guild, icon_url = guild.icon_url)
    emb.add_field(name = "**Status is**", value = '**{}**'.format(
        member.status).replace('dnd', '**Do not disturb**'))
    emb.add_field(name = '** **', value = '** **')
    if member.activity is not None:
        emb.add_field(name = "**Activity is**", value = '**{}**'.format(member.activity.name))
    else:
        emb.add_field(name = "**Activity is**".format(member.mention), value = '**Nothing**')
    emb.add_field( name = "**Roles are**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.roles ).replace('[<Role id=', '').replace('<Role id=', '').replace("name='", '').replace("'>", '').replace('@everyone', '').replace(']', '').replace('@everyone,', ''), inline = False )
    emb.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.roles` returns you a list of roles. For getting every name of the roles, you should make a `for loop`. Then you should save role names in another list.

```py
role_names = []
for role in member.roles:
    role_names.append(role.name)
```

So here, I made a `for loop` for `member.roles` and I save the `role.name` inside the `role_names` list.

After that, you should return this list into a `string` so your embed can seem better. For this, you can use `str.join()`.

```py
role_names = []
for role in member.roles:
    role_names.append(role.name)
role_names = ', '.join(role_names)
```

So if you add this to your code, then if you do

`emb.add_field(name="**Roles are**", value=f'**{role_names}**')`

it will return you a list of role names like **Admin, Owner, Moderator**.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```py
emb.add_field( name = "**Roles were**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.roles ).replace('[<Role id=', '').replace('<Role id=', '').replace("name='", '').replace("'>", '').replace('@everyone', '').replace(']', '').replace('@everyone,', ''), inline = False )
```

To:

```py
emb.add_field(name="**Roles were**", value=f"**{', '.join([role.name for role in member.roles])}**")
```

Comment: THANKSS! I'm new in python so I need to learn more... xD.